# How do I memory-efficiently process all rows of a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, cursor

I have a MySQL table with 237 million rows. I want to process all of these rows and update them with new values.

I do have sequential ID's, so I could just use a lot of `select` statements:

```
where id = '1'
where id = '2'
```

This is the method mentioned in [Sequentially run through a MYSQL table with 1,000,000 records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521318/sequentially-run-through-a-mysql-table-with-1-000-000-records).

But I'd like to know if there is a faster way using something like a cursor that would be used to sequentially read a big file without needing to load the full set into memory. The way I see it, a cursor would be much faster than running millions of `select` statements to get the data back in manageable chunks.

Comment: the method you linked is unrelated/ If you take it as a permit to loop  `where id = '1'`, `'2'`, ... you have read it wrong.

Comment: What are the values to which you want the data updated?  Are they in any way related to something that's already in the database?  If so, use them directly.  If not, insert your new data into a temporary table and then update against that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally, you get the DBMS to do the work for you.  You make the SQL statement so it runs solely in the database, not returning data to the application.  All else apart, this saves the overhead of 237 million messages to the client and 237 million messages back to the server.

Whether this is feasible depends on the nature of the update:

- Can the DBMS determine what the new values should be?
- Can you get the necessary data into the database so that the DBMS can determine what the new values should be?
- Will every single one of the 237 million rows be changed, or only a subset?
- Can the DBMS be used to determine the subset?
- Will any of the `id` values be changed at all?

If the `id` values will never be changed, then you can arrange to partition the data into manageable subsets, for any flexible definition of 'manageable'.

You may need to consider transaction boundaries; can it all be done in a single transaction without blowing out the logs? If you do operations in subsets rather than as a single atomic transaction, what will you do if your driving process crashes at 197 million rows processed?  Or the DBMS crashes at that point? How will you know where to resume operations to complete the processing?

Comment: I can indeed write a single sql statement (all info is in the db).  It is a production db however,  and I am concerned about extended locking (I am using innodb, so maybe that isn't an issue?)  I do need to update every record in the table.   At the moment I'm leaning towards using the index to grab 1000 rows at a time.  To answer your final question, there will be no changes to the index values.

Comment: As long as your business won't make erroneous decisions based on the post-updated values of the first 200 million rows and pre-updated values of the last 37 million rows, then a trickle update in batches of 1000 at a time is reasonable. The fact that the `id` columns won't be changing simplifies your life dramatically. Do make sure you use explicit transactions, and keep a record, somehow, of which rows have been updated.  Maybe add a table to the database to record which rows have been processed, so run the 1000 rows update, then update the new table to reflect those changes, and then commit.

Comment: This is a very wise and thoughtful answer.  +1 for the clear and definitive language. Thanks.